# Driving multiwinding current transformer

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement, sinusoidal

About the circuit below:

1. I'm using a Current Transformer with two identical secondary windings, L1 and L2. I can use them indistinctively since they are 1:1. The relationship with the primary is 1000:1, that means 1A in the primary is 1 mA in the secondary.
2. I'm using L1 as main secondary. I'm using L2 to inject a current for testing. Whatever current I put in L2, it appears in L1. Whenever I decide to inject current to L2 (preferably when there's no primary current) I activate a PWM from the micro and make it pass through high pass filter to inject only AC current to L2.
3. When I pass a current through primary, I get the expected voltage across the burden resistor R18. See waveform 1. That waveform corresponds to the max current I will measure. I have left L2 without burden resistor, because otherwise it would load L1.
4. As L1 & L2 are 1:1 I should see the same voltage across L2. But here is the point, I see a much higher voltage. See waveform 2. Why is this?

So, somehow I need to provide some kind of isolation between L2 and the microcontroller to protect it against this high AC voltage. Also, L2 needs to be unloaded so it does not affect signal in L1. Any suggestion on this? I tried to add an [analog switch like this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/SN74LVC2G66) between the cap and L2, but this switch has some internal diodes that clips the signal seen in L2 then it clips it in L1.

[image]

Waveform 1

[image]

Waveform 2

[image]

Comment: You should link to the data sheet of the CT.

Answer (score 1):

It is a must to keep the burden of a current transformer always connected across its secondary winding. This is to eliminate the danger of high voltage induced in the secondary winding that could also result in damage to the current transformer caused by insulation breakdown.

This applies equally to the dual windings of a current transformer intended for metering and fault tripping purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you to think of voltage and current transformers as being complimentary.

- Voltage transformers are unloaded when open-circuit. They don't like short-circuits.
- Current transformers are unloaded when short-circuited. They don't like open-circuits.

If you open-circuit a CT secondary and drive a current through the primary then the CT output voltage will try to rise enough to force the secondary current to flow. On a good quality transformer the voltage may rise high enough to break down the air and arcing will result.

> When I pass a current through primary, I get the expected voltage across the burden resistor R18. See waveform 1. That waveform corresponds to the max current I will measure.

That's a good sign.

> I have left L2 without burden resistor, because otherwise it would load L1.

It's the opposite to what you think. The load seen by the CT is lowest when the secondary is shorted out.

> As L1 & L2 are 1:1 I should see the same voltage across L2.

No. Remember that it's a CT, not a VT. You should see the same *current* in L2. A simple thought experiment is to consider doubling the value of your burden resistor on L1. This will double the voltage reading on L1. Why would it double the voltage reading on L2? (It wouldn't.)

Using the complimentary VT analogy it would be like having a resistive load on one secondary and a short-circuit on the other and expecting the same currents to flow in each secondary.

> But here is the point, I see a much higher voltage. See waveform 2. Why is this?

It's the CT trying to generate enough voltage to get the same current to flow in L1 and L2.

> So, somehow I need to provide some kind of isolation between L2 and the microcontroller to protect it against this high AC voltage.

Short out L2.

Comment: You mean that by shorting out L2 does not affect the current I should see on L1, right? When I want to inject current to L2 with the microcontroller, it should stay shorted?

Comment: That's correct. It then provides minimum loading to the magnetic core. On an industrial circuit you would never open circuit a CT while on load. They would always have a shorting link somewhere in the circuit so that you could safely short it out before disconnecting the meter.

Comment: I will test that. So the circuit shown above is correct?

Comment: I mean, should I leave L2 shorted whenever I'm not using it, and when I want the inject the current, then open it?

Comment: Yes, but your current drive needs to be able to be driven if it's connected when current is input on the primary or on L1.

Comment: The current drive is basically the microcontroller. What do you suggest to improve trhe drive circuit? Could I place the analog switch or a FET in parallel with L2 to short it out?

Comment: I don't know. I'd have to think it over but I'm working on something else.

Comment: I tested shorting L2, but then current in L1 gets halved.

Comment: Hmmm. Without knowing your CT and your setup I can't comment further. I'm afraid I won't have time to look at it in the next week. If you don't get a good answer to this question then post a new one specifically on your CT setup but include a link to its datasheet. Reference this question if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe that a burden resistor on L2 would load L1; it would sap energy from the core but shouldn’t affect the voltage on L1, provided that L1 is fed from a low-impedance source.  In active service, having a load on L1 and L2 should be fine, as the energy in the core should (hopefully) be plenty to drive both.  Why L1 outputs a higher voltage than that applied to L2 is a mystery though, possibly there’s parasitic inductance if L1 and K2 are physically separate, so the load on L1 doesn’t directly load the magnetic field that L2 sees.